# Error in SQL syntax: Update query error

Tags: php, mysql

I working in my login form and 1 requirement is to have a change password. For some reason I'm always getting this error->  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' SET 'password'=SHA1('123') WHERE 'email'='mac.pader@yahoo.com'' at line 1.

```
<?php
$page_title = 'Change Your Password';
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('userdb');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
 //Start the Session
session_start();


if (isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
//3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// Check for a new password and match
// against the confirmed password:
if (!empty($_POST['pass1'])) {
if ($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
$errors[] = 'Your new password did not match the confirmed password.';
} else {
$np = $_POST['pass1'];
}
//3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT userid FROM `users` WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['np'] = $np;
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
// Make the UPDATE query:
$query = "UPDATE 'users' SET 'password'=SHA1('$np') WHERE 'email'='$email'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo"$np and $email";
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){

}else{

// Public message:
echo '<h1>System Error</h1>
<p class="error">Your password could not be changed due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
// Debugging message:
echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
}
// Include the footer and quit the script (to not show the form).
//include ('includes/footer.html');
exit();
} else { // Invalid email address/password combination.
echo '<h1>Error!</h1>
<p class="error">The email address and password do not match those on file.</p>';
echo"$num";
}
} 



//3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo'<h1>Thank you!</h1>
<p>Your password has been updated. You can now Log-In!</p><p><br /></p>';

}else{
echo'try again';
}

mysql_close($select_db);
exit();
//3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
?>

// Check for a new password and match
// against the confirmed password:
if (!empty($_POST['pass1'])) {
if ($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
$errors[] = 'Your new password did not match the confirmed password.';
} else {
$np = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['pass1']));
}
} else {
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your new password.';
}

?>
```

Comment: IN the update query change the quotes around identifiers to backticks like in your select statement. Btw you code is wide open to SQL injections ...

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs which don't intermix with each other; especially `$np = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['pass1']));`

Comment: So, still no solution yet?

Comment: yes im currently working on it again

Answer (score 1):

You have to use backticks arround table and field names not single quotes:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `Password`=SHA1('$np') WHERE `email`='$email'
```

Also you should not use mysql_* functions because this API is depricated.

Comment: OP is also mixing APIs using `mysqli_error($dbc)` and will never get the error should one exist. Not to mention an open door to injection and storing passwords in plain text. May as well just leave the front door open and throw away the keys ;-) Edit: also prematurely closing with `?>` `// Check for a new password and match` etc.

Comment: thank you for your response! :) however the error change into parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"users"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: There's another instance where OP is mixing APIs. You should have spotted that.